# Interop.Powerpoint: How to clear of undo (stack)

Tags: c#, winforms, vsto, powerpoint, office-interop

is it possible to clear the undo stack of PowerPoint from my add-in? I've found that in the `Interop.Word` there is an `ActiveDocument.UndoClear` method but there isn't such method for Presentation object.

Thanks

Comment: There is no native support in the object model to support this in PowerPoint.

Comment: @ShyamPillai unfortunately I suspected that. Any ideas on how to do it? I wouldn't lilke to close and reopen the document.

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.RemoveDocumentInformation(PpRemoveDocInfoType.ppRDISlideUpdateInformation);
```